# Using .getchildren() on a tree always returns a list of length 1

Tags: python, insert, treeview

anyone who is kind enough to help. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm damned if I know what it is.

As a preliminary to making a list of directories in a ttk.Treeview component I am trying to teach myself how to add items to the tree and list them. The simple test routine I have written is supposed to add a new child to the last item in the tree. Unfortunately the list created by getchildren() is always just one item long, containing only the root, and new items always get added as children of the root - and do not turn up in the list from getchildren(). The items themselves are added:

Here is the relevant code:

```
# Create a treeview object.
tree1 = ttk.Treeview(left_frame)
tree1.insert('', 'end', 'tree-view test', text="Tree View Root")
# And put it in the window.
tree1.pack()

def tree_experiment(tree_current):
    for i_counter in range(10):
        list_children = tree_current.get_children()
        for child_item in list_children:
            print(child_item)
        last_item = list_children[len(list_children) - 1]
        str_counter = str(i_counter)
        test_item = tree_current.insert(last_item, 'end', '', text='Inserted item ' + str_counter)
        if tree_current.exists(test_item):
            print("Found new item in tree: {}".format(test_item))
        else:
            print("New item in tree not found")
        print(str(len(list_children)) + " items in the tree")
```

The output is:

```
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I001
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I002
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I003
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I004
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I005
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I006
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I007
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I008
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I009
1 items in the tree
tree-view test
Found new item in tree: I00A
1 items in the tree
```

And here is a screenshot showing that the items have been added, if only as children of the root:

[image: Screenshot of TTK application]

If anyone can help, thank you, and I apologise if I have repeated someone else's question.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out. getchildren() only returns the direct children of a node, not all the children recursively. By keeping track of the last node added I was able to get the effect I wanted.